# unclear with this thread concept

Tags: java, synchronization

```
class A extends Thread { 
    ThreadDemo demo; 
    public A(ThreadDemo td) { 
        demo = td; 
    } 
    public void run() { 
        demo.doSomething(); 
    } 
}
public class ThreadDemo { 
    int count = 1; 
    public synchronized void doSomething() { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            System.out.println(count++); 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ThreadDemo demo = new ThreadDemo(); 
        A a1 = new A(demo); 
        A a2 = new A(demo); 
        a1.start(); 
        a2.start(); 
    } 
}
```

1.want to know the needy of this constructor in this code. and explain how demo reference works in class A

p.s: i'm new to this concept so plz assist me with yur valuable ans!
thnx in advance!

Comment: The question you are asking isn't about threads at all, but rather just about objects and how they work.

Comment: You have to have a minimal understanding of the problem.  I suggest you do some reading about Java in general.  Maybe: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html

Answer (score 2):

**1.why demo obj is passed into into class A?**

Because you have constructor of Class A defined so.

```
public A(ThreadDemo td) 
{ 
    demo = td; 
}
```

**2.if i replace A a1 = new A(demo); with Thread a1 = new Thread(demo); it 'll produce constructor Thread.Thread(ThreadGroup,Runnable,String,long) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) why this error appear?**

Because Thread class do not take object of ThreadDemo class as parameter. However using polymorphism you can do something like

```
Thread a1 = new A(demo);
```

**3.why they are passing demo as reference in class A**

I think you intended to ask `why they are passing the same reference in both the threads` or the answer is same as the 1st question. They are passing same reference so that only one thread can operate on your doSomething() method of ThreadDemo class(maybe the goal was to demonstrate synchronization).

Comment: thanks bro yur ans no.2 was helpful and one more doubt how the constructor works when class A obj created. and explain needy of this constructor in this code

Comment: When any instance of an class is created the corresponding constructor is invoked. If a superclass constructor is explicitly not called from the constructor(1st line) using super() then java compiler put a call to default constructor as the 1st line of the given constructor.In your case you are creating a new class A object as new A(demoObjectYouCreated) so it will invoke the corresponding constructor  public A(ThreadDemo td) of your class. Note that if you specify a parameterized(non default) constructor then the compiler will not create the default one for you.

Comment: As of why such constructor is needed in Class A you have to read synchronization.Google it! Just to answer it generically you have a common object on which you synchronize methods(basically you can think it as of lock). Only one thread can execute these synchronized methods(only more thread can acquire the objects monitor at a time).